# Mule ESB - Why is the main xml file getting deleted

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio

I have had the problem with the main xml file getting deleted. It is located in src/main/app. The file in the flows folder is still there, xx.mflow but when i try to open this file, I get the error "Could not open the editor: assertion failed: " and the rest of the page is blank.

I can open the .mflow file in a text editor, but it looks nothing like the xml that was deleted.

The contents of this file is xml with root node  it defines the global elements with properties and flows, but is very different from what I am used to working with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><mule-configuration xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.com/tooling/messageflow" name="coiservice">    <global-element name="Property Placeholder" type="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/property-placeholder" entity-id="Property Placeholder#1"> etc....
```

is it possible to generate the original xml from this .mflow?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using SVN plugins in MULE pls make sure you have committed both .mflow and main.xml .. It happens when people used to forget to commit both the files and then update with the SVN

Comment: We are using mercurial plugin, but this most recent occurrence was on a new project that had not been committed yet. Only saved locally

Comment: You shouldn't store .mflow files in any version control system. These are the files generated by Studio and are being regenerated from .xml when missing.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this file generated by the .xml, is there a way to do the reverse? my .mflow is still in tact, well I saved it in a different location in hopes that I can do this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening `.mflow` file from windows explorer. Right click and open with any text editor like Notepad++. You may be able to create `.xml` from this if it is not corrupted.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question, I can open it in a text editor. The contents are definitely items that I have added to my flow, but the .mflow file is way different than the main xml file. I am looking for a way to convert it.